# Get bootStrapContext token from ClaimsPrincipal in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, azure-active-directory

I am developing application in MVC and i want to authenticate my users with Azure active directory.

To achieve this, I have created application in Azure active directory with the application URL and also assigned permissions to application.

I have also configured my application to use Azure AD authentication. Now when i try to access the bootstrapContext.Token, it comes always null.

I am using below method to access the bootstrapContext.

```
var bootstrapContext = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identities.First().BootstrapContext as System.IdentityModel.Tokens.BootstrapContext;

string userAccessToken = bootstrapContext.Token;
```

I have searched on this and found that i have to update my web.config. So i have updated it as below

```
<system.identityModel>
<identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
<system.identityModel>
```

My main goal is to use UserAssertion for authContext.AcquireToken method. 
And UserAssertion requires bootstrapContext.Token.

As per suggestion from MvdD, I have also tried below thing

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
{
    Wtrealm = realm,
    MetadataAddress = metadataUri,
    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        SaveSigninToken = true
    }
});
```

but now, i am getting below error

```
AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. AADSTS50027: Invalid JWT token. Token format not valid.

Trace ID: 0d052707-9aaf-4037-b7c9-4c4aa7cfcc72

Correlation ID: 9a00573b-cfe9-4665-ab81-c0a03eace9d8

Timestamp: 2016-02-08 05:18:01Z
```

So can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not really clear from your question which protocol or what libraries you are using.

If you are using Katana middleware, you should set the `SaveSigninToken` property in the appropriate `AuthenticationOptions` class. For the WS-Federation protocol, it would look something like this:
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
    new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Wtrealm = realm,
        MetadataAddress = metadataUri,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            SaveSigninToken = true
        }
    }
);
```

If you are using `System.IdentityModel`, you need to set the [`SaveBootstrapContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.IdentityModel.Configuration.IdentityConfiguration.SaveBootstrapContext);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true) property on the `IdentityConfiguration` object.

Comment: Solved my long standing problem, I was using TokenValidationParameters, and didnt have the  SaveSigninToken = true

Comment: I used this but still bootstrap context is coming null